# Spring select query is not displaying data on page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

When i run project , it just displays table structure. not the data.
everything is working fine. just it displays table structure and the Email and Password header. but no data is displaying.

**controller_fetch.java**

```
public class controller_fetch extends model.modelclass {
SqlRowSet srs=null;
ArrayList arraylist=null;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list")
    public ArrayList list(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            arraylist = new ArrayList();
            modelclass obj = new modelclass();
            SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
            dataSource = new dbconnection.connection().getConnection(dataSource);
            JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info";
             srs = jt.queryForRowSet(sql);

            while (srs.next()) {
                obj.setEmailid(srs.getString("email_id"));
                obj.setPwd(srs.getString("pwd"));
            arraylist.add(obj);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arraylist;
    }

}
```

**list.jsp**

***${arraylist} is always null. not getting return value from controller.***

```
         <table>
            <tr><td><b>Email</b></td><td><b>Password</b></td></tr>
            <c:forEach  items="${arraylist}" var="value">
            <tr>
                <td>${value.email_id}</td>
                <td>${value.pwd}</td>               
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>            
        </table>
```

Comment: Did you try debugging ?

Comment: yes..  ${arraylist} is always null. not getting return value from controller

Comment: have you tried using `<c:out>`? EDIT: ah wait if ${arraylist} is always null then it shouldn't matter. try it anyways

Comment: mmm.. not working ,,, bcs arrylist is null

Comment: If you're using MVC, I'd just set the return type as `ModelAndView` and just use `addObject()`

Comment: please help me with posting code ,, i am new in spring

Comment: I'll post an answer. One second

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is much easier if you're using Spring MVC. I'm still also new, but I still hope this works for you.

In your Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();        
        try {

        arraylist = new ArrayList();
        modelclass obj = new modelclass();
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource = new dbconnection.connection().getConnection(dataSource);
        JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info";
         srs = jt.queryForRowSet(sql);

        while (srs.next()) {
            obj.setEmailid(srs.getString("email_id"));
            obj.setPwd(srs.getString("pwd"));
        arraylist.add(obj);
        }
      model.addObject("arraylist", arraylist);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return model;
}

}
```

And in the jsp

```
 <table>
        <tr><td><b>Email</b></td><td><b>Password</b></td></tr>
        <c:forEach  items="${arraylist}" var="value">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${value.email_id}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${value.pwd}" /></td>               
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>            
    </table>
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: put ModelAndView above `try`

Comment: firstly on controller page after while loop has completed **arraylist** gets 4 rows. fine as there are 4 rows in database. but in **arraylist** every row gets ***same*** values.

Comment: @PapanDebnath The controller returns the same values?

Comment: Arraylist gets 4 rows .. but everyrow gets same values.. previous value gets replaced by new value

Comment: Right now, I can only advise to debug it and tell me when in the controller the values are being replaced.